# Stokes's theorem and problem

Tags: calculus

This is not a question. 
I just uploaded this problem for the posting.

If you evaluate $\displaystyle{\int_{S}\text{curl} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{\sigma}     }$ where $\displaystyle{ \mathbf{F} = \langle {\rm{exp}}(xz) +2y{\rm{exp}}(x^2+y^2) , {\rm{ln}} (\pi+{\rm{exp}}(y^{2n+1})) +3x {\rm{exp}}(x^2 +y^2), 3x^2 y \rangle }$ and $S$ is a positively oriented surface defined by $z=1-x^2 - y^2 , ~x^2+y^2 \le 1$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then
 you can have $\displaystyle{\int_{S}\text{curl} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{\sigma}     }=\pi^a e^b$.  Now, find $2000a+30b$.

Comment: If that is not a question, then what do you want?

Comment: @DonAntonio  The answer for this problem is the key for some open chat. I can't use latex on that system.

Comment: Oh, I see...Well, it is odd but I won't downvote it neither vote to close it.